# Writing strings to csv with library in Python

Tags: python, csv

I tried to write strings to csv.

```
import csv
f = open('ttt.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='')
wr = csv.writer(f)

for t in [['Love it', 'doenst matter']] :
    lin = ''.join(t)
    print(type(lin))

    wr.writerow([lin])

f.close()
```

Normally, I expected and hope it will be written :

```
"Love itdoenst matter"
```

In this manner, it should be saved like :

```
Love itdoenst matter |
```

But actually it is written on csv file without quotes :

```
Love itdoenst matter
```

So in CSV file doesn't treat it as one element of string. So it saves Love itdoesnt matter on different columns.

Like

```
Love | itdoesnt | matter
```

Don't know why this happen

Comment: The issue is that you haven't told the csv writer that you want to use space as your delimiter, so it doesn't quote elements containing a space character. Default delimiter is a comma.

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you do not tell the `csv` module that you want to delimit your file on spaces - the default is comma, as per the name. You can specify the delimiter as follows:

```
wr = csv.writer(f, delimiter=" ")
```

Under default `csv` quoting, this will then place quote marks around any elements containing the delimiter character.